# BluemixのNode-Redについて教えてください。

Tags: bluemix

Bluemixの中にある、Node-Redというフローエディター簡単にプログラムが作れて楽しいです。
Node-Redって、IBMさんが開発した製品でしょうか？
使用方法や使用例をもっと詳しく知りたいのですが、良いガイドやサンプルが纏まったサイトがあれば教えて下さい。

Answer (score 1):

Node-Redは、[IBMのEmerging Technologyチーム](https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/blogs/et/entry/home?lang=ja)が開発したもので、オープンソースのプロジェクトです。

様々なサンプルFlowが、公式サイトの[Node-Red Libraryのページ](http://flows.nodered.org/)にUploadされていますので、参考にしてみてください。サンプルのImport方法は、こちらの[Qiitaの記事](http://qiita.com/asmanabu/items/d9ba9ff0fca745c8c216)が参考になります。

ガイドは、[公式ページのDocumentation](http://nodered.org/docs/)を参照して頂くのが一番かと思いますが、[Qiita](http://qiita.com/tags/bluemix)にも分かりやすい解説が幾つか投稿されているようですので、参考にすると良いと思います。